# Discord Bot, Display the value after choose the question on ".addChoice"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

When I choose question, the answer value is not showing. i want to show the question and the answer.

Choose question: https://ibb.co/6sYLc1P

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("question")
        .setDescription("what do you want to ask me?")
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('question')
                .setDescription('Your question')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: 'How old are you', value: '21' },
                    { name: 'When is your birthday?', value: 'September 8, 2003' },
                    { name: 'What is your favorite color?', value: 'Violet' },
                )),
    execute: async ({ interaction }) => {

        await interaction.reply({ content: 'your question: ${name}' });
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'answer: ${value}' })

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
your question: ${name}
```

[Screenshot output](https://ibb.co/K96yVjw)

**My Expected output:**

```
your question: How old are you?

answer: 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Template Literals if you want ${name} and ${value} to resolve into the value of the variables. https://www.w3schools.com/JS//js_string_templates.asp

So what you have to do is change ' to backtick `

What you have:

```
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'your question: ${name}' });
    await interaction. Reply({ content: 'answer: ${value}' })
```

What it should be:

```
    await interaction.reply({ content: `your question: ${name}` });
    await interaction. Reply({ content: `answer: ${value}` })
```

Update below

I could not find a way to get the text of the choice you select. You can probably store the objects in a separate variable and then search for the for the question from the given answer in the execute function.
But this is how you get the value of the selected choice. It's all in the documentation https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html#choices

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("question")
    .setDescription("what do you want to ask me?")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("question")
        .setDescription("Your question")
        .setRequired(true)
        .addChoices(
          { name: "How old are you", value: "21" },
          { name: "When is your birthday?", value: "September 8, 2003" },
          { name: "What is your favorite color?", value: "Violet" }
        )
    ),
  execute: async (interaction) => {
    const answer = interaction.options.getString("question"); // Gets the value from the selected choice
    await interaction.reply({ content: `answer: ${answer}` });
  },
};
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping but still error "ReferenceError: name is not defined"

Comment: Here the message on dc https://ibb.co/x8JSYP0

Comment: I've updated my answer. The documentation tells you how to get the value of the choice. But I could not find a way to get the name of the choice.

Comment: Hello, I tried this code, and it worked o_o

Thank you so much!